# Adding Facebook like button with JAde

Tags: facebook, pug, facebook-like

i am trying to implement facebook like button to my jade page 
but  it displays nothing and i have no idea why 
could someone explain me why?
here is code

```
div.row
              div.form-group
                div.col-md-3
                  #fb-root
                    script.
                      (function (d, s, id) {
                        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                        js = d.createElement(s);
                        js.id = id;
                        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0";
                        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
                    // Your like button code
                    .fb-like(data-href='http://fsa.kg/', data-layout='standard', data-action='like', data-show-faces='true')
```

Here is html code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://fsa.kg/" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML as output to the browser so we can see what was produced by this code.  This jade view/template surely doesn't output "nothing", but if it is truly "nothing" then you have a problem in your route and not the view.

Comment: u mean to send an html version like above i have done ?